# Save multiple graphs one after another in one pdf file

Tags: r, plot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to print R graphics to multiple pages of a PDF and multiple PDFs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395410/how-to-print-r-graphics-to-multiple-pages-of-a-pdf-and-multiple-pdfs)

I am new to R and have a quick question. The following code writes one .pdf file for each graph. I would like to add figures one after another in ONE pdf file. Thank you so much. Greatly appreciate any help.

```
i=5  
while (i<=10)   
{   
  name1="C:\\temp\\"  
  num=i   
  ext = ".pdf"  
  path3 = paste(name1,num,ext)  
  par(mfrow = c(2,1))  
  pdf(file=path3)  
  VAR1=rnorm(i)  
  VAR2=rnorm(i)  
  plot(VAR1,VAR2)  
  dev.off()  
  i=i+1  
}
```

Comment: Check out the `onefile` option in `help(pdf)`.

Answer (score 32):

Just move your `pdf()` function call and your `dev.off()` call outside the loop:

```
somePDFPath = "C:\\temp\\some.pdf"
pdf(file=somePDFPath)  

for (i in seq(5,10))   
{   
  par(mfrow = c(2,1))
  VAR1=rnorm(i)  
  VAR2=rnorm(i)  
  plot(VAR1,VAR2)   
} 
dev.off()
```

Note my use the the `seq()` function to loop instead of `while()` with a counter variable.

Comment: I tired this, but it does not save the file.

Comment: @user2806363, I just tried the above snippet in R 3.1.1 and it works exactly the same as it did 3 years ago.  My guess is your file path is invalid for your setup...

Comment: Yes, it works.for my case I have to save aroud 10000 plots in one pdf file. how can I put more than one plot in one page instead of puting one plot per page?  I don't want to have .pdf file with 10000 pages. I like to have .pdf file around 2000 pages.

Comment: @user2806363, look at the help for `par`, in particular the `mfrow` option.  `pdf(file=somePath); par(mfrow=c(2,2)); plot(x); plot(y); plot(z); plot(q); dev.off()`, this would create one page with the plots arranged 2x2...

Comment: This works fine for me.  Thank you Mark, it was simple and just what I needed.

Comment: However, it is not generalizable for automated plots of model results, that partition the screen as they want (usually 2x2) and produce >4 plots