# How can I export multiple plots as a pdf in R?

Tags: r

How can I export multiple plots as a pdf in R ?
Does anyone know What is the command for this ?

Comment: I ended up here before I found the other links. So just posting the links to previous/better answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395410/how-to-print-r-graphics-to-multiple-pages-of-a-pdf-and-multiple-pdfs https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7534606/save-multiple-graphs-one-after-another-in-one-pdf-file

Answer (score 10):

You may want to try this:

```
pdf(file='plot.pdf')
plot(1:10)
dev.off()
```

Since you didn't provide any [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) I just give you the example written above. See the documentation by doing `?pdf` and `?dev.off()`

Answer (score 3):

Multiple plots would be (adding to [Jilber](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1315767/jilber))

```
pdf(file='plot.pdf')
par(mfrow=(c(1,3)))
plot(1:10)
plot(rnorm(10)
plot(rnorm(10)
dev.off()
```

Answer (score 2):

or You can use the plyr package to create a pdf with multiple plots

```
library(ply)
pdf("plots.pdf", width = 7, height = 7)
d_ply(df, .(z), failwith(NA, function(x){plot(x$y,main=unique(z))}), .print=TRUE)
dev.off()
```

were df is a data frame containing a conditional factor (z) and a target variable (y). You will get as many plots as z levels, all included in a pdf report.

Answer (score 0):

The above answers will help you to export the plots in table but if you want them to be in table like 2-3 graphs in 1 row, you can use following code:

```
pdf("Export_Plots.pdf", width = 16 , height = 10, title = "EDA Plots for data")
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
for(i in 1:10){
  par(mar = c(5,4,4,5)+.1)
  plot(i)
}

dev.off()
```

Please check below link for more detail:
https://topbullets.com/2017/04/19/exporting-multiple-graphs-in-same-plot-to-pdf-in-r-topbullets-com/