# How to append a plot to an existing pdf file

Tags: r, pdf, plot

I want to append a plot to an existing pdf long after `dev.off()` has been called*.  After reading the `pdf()` help file and after reading the Q & A [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395410/how-to-print-r-graphics-to-multiple-pages-of-a-pdf-and-multiple-pdfs) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7534606/save-multiple-graphs-one-after-another-in-one-pdf-file), I'm pretty sure it can't be done in R. But, maybe some of you smarter people have a solution that I wasn't able to find.

```
pdf("Append to me.%03d.pdf",onefile=T)
plot(1:10,10:1) #First plot (page 1)
dev.off()
pdf("Append to me.%03d.pdf",onefile=T)
plot(1:10,rep(5,10)) #Want this one on page 2
dev.off()
```

*This not a duplicate of the questions linked above because I want to append to a pdf file *after* the pdf device has been closed.

Comment: Maybe this [Tyler Rinker's video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=Eqi4-tuvKkI) is helpful to you. It's not an R answer, but it is interesting.

Comment: What OS are you on? You could pipe the output through a command to merge the pdf stream with the existing PDF.

Comment: +1 An `append.pdf` function would be handy.

Comment: @Jilber.  This is an excellent question, I should've tried to address it in my original question.  I'm calibrating a simulation  where the runs take ~1 hour and the entire calibration process can take a week or more.  At the end of each run, I want to save a historical plot that I can compare to past runs.  I don't think it is feasible to keep the device open for a week+ if I have other plots that I want to produce during the simulation runs.  Eventually, I would like to do some of the runs in parallel and consolidate the outputs into one pdf file.

Comment: @Gavin-Simpson I am conducting my runs on a RedHat box which I access either via the terminal or via RStudio server.  But, there are others on my "team" who use OS X and Windows and I would like a solution that would work on those OS's as well. Until then, I'd be interested in seeing the pipe command you proppose.

Comment: @Jilber Just took a look at Tyler Rinker's video.  Thanks for that useful Windows solution.  My client machine is a Mac, and OS X provides parallel functionality with the "Preview" application.  But, as I indicate above, I'd prefer to do this directly in R in a platform independent way.

Comment: See [here](http://trinkerrstuff.wordpress.com/2012/10/08/splitting-and-combining-r-pdf-visuals/) Anandas' Second comment where he provides an R solution for several OS.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You could use `recordPlot` to store each plot in a `list`, then write them all to a pdf file at the end with `replayPlot`. Here's an example:

```
num.plots <- 5
my.plots <- vector(num.plots, mode='list')

for (i in 1:num.plots) {
    plot(i)
    my.plots[[i]] <- recordPlot()
}
graphics.off()

pdf('myplots.pdf', onefile=TRUE)
for (my.plot in my.plots) {
    replayPlot(my.plot)
}
graphics.off()
```

Comment: Excellent suggestion, I wasn't aware of `recordPlot`.  Just did some quick testing and it looks like it will do nicely.  THANKS!

Answer (score 19):

If you are willing to install the small, free, platform-independent [**pdftk**](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) utililty, you could use a system call from R to have it stitch all of your figures together:

```
## A couple of example pdf docs
pdf("Append to me.1.pdf")
plot(1:10,10:1)
dev.off()

pdf("Append to me.2.pdf")
plot(1:10,rep(5,10)) 
dev.off()

## Collect the names of the figures to be glued together
ff <- dir(pattern="Append to me")
## The name of the pdf doc that will contain all the figures
outFileName <- "AllFigs.pdf"

## Make a system call to pdftk
system2(command = "pdftk",
        args = c(shQuote(ff), "cat output", shQuote(outFileName)))

## The command above is equiv. to typing the following at the system command line
## pdftk "Append to me.1.pdf" "Append to me.2.pdf" cat output "AllFigs.pdf"
```

Comment: @josh-obrien Neat!  I'll tuck this one away for future use as well.

Comment: Love this solution

Answer (score 6):

This is horribly hacky and probably belies my limited UNIX shell fu, but it works for me on a Fedora 17 box with the [**pdfjam** package](http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/statistics/staff/academic-research/firth/software/pdfjam) installed (not an R package, but from the YUM repos)

```
pdf("pdf1.pdf")
plot(1:10)
dev.off()

pdf("| pdfjoin --outfile \"pdf2.pdf\" && pdfjoin pdf1.pdf pdf2.pdf --outfile pdf1.pdf && rm pdf2.pdf")
plot(10:1)
dev.off()
```

The output in R is:

```
> pdf("| pdfjoin --outfile \"pdf2.pdf\" && pdfjoin pdf1.pdf pdf2.pdf --outfile pdf1.pdf && rm pdf2.pdf")## && pdfunite joined.pdf tmp.pdf joined.pdf && rm tmp.pdf")
> plot(10:1)
> dev.off()
          ----
  pdfjam: This is pdfjam version 2.08.
  pdfjam: Reading any site-wide or user-specific defaults...
          (none found)
  pdfjam: No PDF/JPG/PNG source specified: input is from stdin.
  pdfjam: Effective call for this run of pdfjam:
          /usr/bin/pdfjam --fitpaper 'true' --rotateoversize 'true' --suffix joined --outfile pdf2.pdf -- /dev/stdin - 
  pdfjam: Calling pdflatex...
  pdfjam: Finished.  Output was to 'pdf2.pdf'.
          ----
  pdfjam: This is pdfjam version 2.08.
  pdfjam: Reading any site-wide or user-specific defaults...
          (none found)
  pdfjam: Effective call for this run of pdfjam:
          /usr/bin/pdfjam --fitpaper 'true' --rotateoversize 'true' --suffix joined --outfile pdf1.pdf -- pdf1.pdf - pdf2.pdf - 
  pdfjam: Calling pdflatex...
  pdfjam: Finished.  Output was to 'pdf1.pdf'.
null device 
          1
```

Basically, `pdfjoin` will take input from `stdin` if it is the only input file so I pipe the  output from `pdf()` to the `pdfjoin` program and specify the output file using the `--outfile` argument. Then using `&&` is join the original `pdf1.pdf` with the `pdf2.pdf` just created, specifying that the output PDF is `pdf1.pdf`, the name of the original PDF.

Comment: I'll add that it would probably be easier to write a temporary pdf file, then call `pdfjoin` directly using `system()` to merge the PDFs and then delete the temporary one, but the above does work.

Comment: Woah! Your UNIX shell fu is much stronger than mine.  I'm going to tuck this away for the future.  Until then, I think mplourde's solution will meet immediate my needs.

Answer (score 3):

I found this excellent work recently (not attempting to claim it as my own)

https://jonkimanalyze.wordpress.com/2014/07/24/r-compile-png-files-into-pdf/

It's not quite what the OP was asking for, but the reason I like it is that I often have quite dense scatterplots and other plots that don't respond particularly well to window resizing etc. within a pdf. However I need to produce multi page output. So if the plots are data-dense I render them as .pngs and then use the above function to recombine at the end.

```
merge.png.pdf <- function(pdfFile, pngFiles, deletePngFiles=FALSE) {

  pdf(pdfFile)

  n <- length(pngFiles)

  for( i in 1:n) {


    pngFile <- pngFiles[i]

    pngRaster <- readPNG(pngFile)

    grid.raster(pngRaster, width=unit(0.8, "npc"), height= unit(0.8, "npc"))

    if (i < n) plot.new()

  }

  dev.off()

  if (deletePngFiles) {

    unlink(pngFiles)
  }

}
```