# Combine LaTeX with R markdown and pandoc

Tags: r, latex, rstudio

I have created a `R markdown` (RStudio) document and I would like to have that output in pdf combined with some part (i.e. first page) of my LaTeX document. So basically, I would like to do some bits with R Markdown (generating some R output) and write something down in LaTeX and have this two combined into 1 pdf document.

What would be the steps? Thx.

Comment: generate TeX from the Rmd (`pandoc -o stuff.tex stuff.rmd`) and `\include{}` it in the LaTeX document?

Comment: @Ben: This would be possibly one option but still wonder whether the Rmd+tex=pdf is possible.

Comment: OK, do you prefer to generate two PDF documents and merge them?

Comment: would that be within R?

Comment: the answer seems yes. Here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13273611/how-to-append-a-plot-to-an-existing-pdf-file,

Comment: Have you tried simply writing your LaTeX code in the .Rmd file? Normally pandoc recognizes LaTeX code, and uses it when converting to PDF. I use basic LaTeX in my .md/.Rmd files all the time, /newline, special symbols, tables and such.

Comment: I don't necessarily think you can merge two *arbitrary* PDF files within R (i.e. without external tools such as `pdftk`) -- the example you linked is for adding a *plot* to an existing PDF ...

Comment: You can merge pdfs in latex with pdfpages.

Answer (score 1):

To demonstrate how to insert pdf pages using the [pdfpages package](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/pdfpages/pdfpages.pdf), I first create
a pdf file with four pages using the `pdf()` command.

The .Rnw (Knitr) script is as following

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\title{An example on how to add external pdf pages}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\section{First section}
\subsection{First subsection}
This is an empty section with a chunk to create one pdf with four pages

<<mtcarsplot, echo = TRUE, eval = TRUE,  fig.show='hide'>>=
library(knitr) 
pdf(file="figure/mtcarsplot.pdf",onefile=TRUE)
ggplot(mpg, aes(drv, model)) +
      geom_point() +
      facet_grid(manufacturer ~ ., scales = "free", space = "free") +
      theme(strip.text.y = element_text(angle = 0))
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg))+ geom_point(aes(colour=factor(cyl), size = qsec))
ggplot(mpg, aes(x=factor(cyl), y=hwy, fill=factor(cyl)))+ geom_violin(scale = "width")
mosaicplot(Titanic, color = TRUE)
dev.off()
@

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Second subsection (phantom)}
\includepdf[pages={1-2,{},4},nup=2x2]{figure/mtcarsplot.pdf}

\end{document}
```

To insert pages for the external document use

```
\includepdf[<key=val>]{<filename>}
```

The simplest will be `\includepdf[pages=-]` which will include all the pages from the document.

The code to include pages is

```
 \includepdf[pages={1-2,{},4}],nup=2x2]{figure/mtcarsplot.pdf}
```

**{1-2,{},4}** means that I included page 1 to 2, a blank page, then page 4.

The other command is **nup=2x2** which has included four pages in two rows and two columns withing the same page.

It is often usefull to include external pdf as *sections* or *subsections* of the document created, this is done with :

```
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Second subsection (phantom)}
```

The output shows the four pages in one page, with one left blank, and the *table of contents* with the *phantom section*.

[image: pdfpage_example]