# Export Plots in R to Existing Pdf without Overwriting

Tags: r

I have two separate scripts that each outputs a large number of plots. I can set the parameters for the plots but I can not easily combine the scripts. I'd like for all the plots to be saved into the same pdf (or tiff, or png, whatever works) in a way that on each page I have 1 figure from script 1 and 1 figure from script 2. My thinking is that I'll have script 1 to output the figures on the left side of the pages, saving space for script 2. Then in script 2, if I can somehow have the plots exported to the same file, only on the right side of the pages WITHOUT overwriting the existing plots. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

I'm also open to other apps that can automatically combine existing pdfs in this way because I actually have already made the plots separately.

TIA

Comment: I'd suggest looking into RMarkdown. It can be used to create various different formats of output, and in combination with a latex installation to create pdfs... You should be able to source your existing files from within the Rmd document.

Comment: Alternatively, you can check out [How to append a plot to an existing pdf file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13273611/how-to-append-a-plot-to-an-existing-pdf-file)