# multiple scatter plots in single Pdf in R

Tags: r, scatter-plot

I have a function which takes a tab delimited file as an input and creates scatter plot for the values(one scatter plot per file) in the tab delimited file.I need a function which can print scatter plots in one pdf file(ie one scatter plot per page).Here is my function which prints one scatterplot per file.

```
scatter.plot=function(file)
  {
  raw.Data=read.delim(file="D:/output/illumina.txt",row.names = 1, dec = ".")
  raw.expression <- raw.Data[,seq(1,dim(raw.Data)[2],2)]
  dim(raw.expression)   
  raw.calls <- raw.Data[,seq(2,dim(raw.Data)[2],2)]
  dim(raw.calls)
  IDs <- colnames(raw.expression)
  for (i in 1:(dim(raw.expression)[2]-1))
  {
  for( j in i:(dim(raw.expression)[2]) )
  {
  if (i != j)
  {          
  pdf(file=paste(directory,"/",IDs[i],"_gegen_",IDs[j],".pdf",sep=""))
  correlation <- round(cor(raw.expression[,i],raw.expression[,j]),2)
  maximum <- max(log2(raw.expression[,i]))
  minimum <- min(log2(raw.expression[,i]))      plot(log2(raw.expression[,i]),log2(raw.expression[,j]),xlab=IDs[i],ylab=IDs[j],pch='.',text(maximum-2,minimum+0.5,labels=paste("R = ",correlation,sep=""),pos=4,offset=0))
  dev.off()
  }         
  }
  }      
  }
```

The above function takes the illumina text file as a input and prints each scatter plots in single pdf.I want all them  in one pdf..

As the illumina text file is large..I ve given a minimal information code for input data is  below

```
input.file=list(ProbeID=c(870131,5310368,1070445,6770328,610373,450431,1050114,770300,3290546),X1692272066AAVGSignal=c(46.1234,48.73746,50.15939,51.36239,53.75028,55.18534,49.32711,49.49868,50.40989),X1692272066ADetectionPval=c(0.5924308,0.4665211,0.3595342,0.213246,0.1390102,0.5443959,0.5291121,0.4461426,0.6914119),X1692272066BAVGSignal=c(49.38838,50.76025,50.41117,50.52384,58.56867,55.49637,48.71999,57.0689,45.99026),X1692272066BDetectionPval=c(0.5851529,0.4556041,0.4905386,0.4818049,0.05604076,0.1441048,0.6375546,0.08515284,0.8377001),X1692272066CAVGSignal=c(52.47962,51.48042,51.93637,50.08885,56.68196,54.18305,52.03677,57.8032,52.71201),X1692272066CDetectionPval=c(0.4708879,0.5553129,0.5145561,0.661572,0.1783115,0.338428,0.5080058,0.1106259,0.4490539))'
```

Please do help me

Comment: Move the `dev.off()` outside the loop.  `pdf` supports multiple plots in a file.

Comment: Also search for something like "[r] pdf multiple" as this is a repeat question.

Comment: you would need to add `onefile = TRUE` inside your `pdf` statement after moving it outside the loop as suggested by @Andrie

Comment: @Ramnath I tried using one file like _" pdf(file=paste(onefile,directory,"/",IDs[i],"_gegen_",IDs[j],".pdf",sep=""))"_,but it says that one file object is not found...In the help file,onefile was used like _"pdf(file = ifelse(onefile, "Rplots.pdf", "Rplot%03d.pdf")"_..In my case i m using _"pdf(file=paste())"_...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to print R graphics to multiple pages of a PDF and multiple PDFs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395410/how-to-print-r-graphics-to-multiple-pages-of-a-pdf-and-multiple-pdfs)

Comment: you need to pass only a single filename to `pdf`. so for example, you can do `pdf(file = 'myfile.pdf', onefile = TRUE)`

Comment: @Ramnath _for(i in 1:(dim(raw.expression)[2]-1)){
    for( j in i:(dim(raw.expression)[2])){    
      if (i != j){          
        pdf(file="Scatterplots.pdf",onefile=TRUE) 
        correlation <- round(cor(raw.expression[,i],raw.expression[,j]),2)
        maximum <- max(log2(raw.expression[,i]))
        minimum <- min(log2(raw.expression[,i]))        plot(log2(raw.expression[,i]),log2(raw.expression[,j]),xlab=IDs[i],ylab=IDs[j],pch='.',text(maximum-2,minimum+0.5,labels=paste("R = ",correlation,sep=""),pos=4,offset=0))}}dev.off()}_

Comment: @Ramnath I tried the above code but it prints pdf which i cannot open when R is running and also only one is getting printed...Please do help me

Comment: move the `pdf` command OUTSIDE your FOR LOOP. also check out the other links posted in the comments.