# Assigning "beanplot" object to variable in R

Tags: r, plot

I have found that the [beanplot](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/beanplot/index.html) is the best way to represent my data. I want to look at multiple beanplots together to visualize my data. Each of my plots contains 3 variables, so each one looks something like what would be generated by this code:

```
library(beanplot)
a <- rnorm(100)
b <- rnorm(100)
c <- rnorm(100)
beanplot(a, b ,c ,ylim = c(-4, 4), main = "Beanplot", 
         col = c("#CAB2D6", "#33A02C", "#B2DF8A"), border = "#CAB2D6")
```

(Would have just included an image but my reputation score is not high enough, sorry)

I have 421 of these that I want to put into one long PDF (*EDIT: One plot per page is fine, this was just poor wording on my part)*. The approach I have taken was to  first generate the beanplots in a for loop and store them in a list at each iteration. Then I will use the `multiplot` function (from the [R Cookbook page on multiplot](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Multiple_graphs_on_one_page_%28ggplot2%29/)) to display all of my plots on one long column so I can begin my analysis.

The problem is that the `beanplot` function does not appear to be set up to assign plot objects as a variable. Example:

```
library(beanplot)
a <- rnorm(100)
b <- rnorm(100)
plot1 <- beanplot(a, b, ylim = c(-5,5), main = "Beanplot", 
                  col = c("#CAB2D6", "#33A02C", "#B2DF8A"), border = "#CAB2D6")
plot1
```

If you then type `plot1` into the R console, you will get back two of the plot parameters but not the plot itself. This means that when I store the plots in the list, I am unable to graph them with multiplot. It will simply return the plot parameters and a blank plot.

This behavior does not seem to be the case with `qplot` for example which will return a plot when you recall the stored plot. Example:

```
library(ggplot2)
a <- rnorm(100)
b <- rnorm(100)
plot2 <- qplot(a,b)
plot2
```

There is no equivalent to the beanplot that I know of in ggplot. Is there some sort of workaround I can use for this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: see the helpfile, under `"#Trick using internal functions to do this with other functions:"`

Comment: It's hard to imagine you want all the plots on one page, and the default for pdf() is to have 'onefile=TRUE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply open a PDF device with `pdf()` and keep the default parameter `onefile=TRUE`. Then call all your `beanplot()`s, one after the other. They will all be in one PDF document, each one on a separate page. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395410/how-to-print-r-graphics-to-multiple-pages-of-a-pdf-and-multiple-pdfs).

Comment: I was so focused on trying to get the plots into a list it never occurred to me to look at the help file for `pdf()`. This worked perfectly. Thank you.