# When I use textplot() and title() after pdf(), my output has the table but not the title. How can I make the title appear?

Tags: r, pdf, text, title, gplots

I am using the following code in R with the gplots package:

```
pdf("filepath")
plot(graph)
textplot(table, cmar=1)
title("My title")
dev.off()
```

My goal is to have a 2-page pdf file with the plot on page 1 and the table with a title on page 2.  Everything works except the title.  When I run just:

```
textplot(table, cmar=1)
title("My title")
```

It properly displays what I would expect the output to be.

Thanks

Comment: Have you created other multi-page PDFs before? If not [check out this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395410/how-to-print-r-graphics-to-multiple-pages-of-a-pdf-and-multiple-pdfs).

Comment: This code already creates a multi page pdf. The problem is that the title does does not appear above the textplot.

Comment: Using your code with my own sample data seems to work fine. I see the title. Could you please post some sample data that reproduces that problem?

Comment: Chistopher,  thanks for responding and testing the code.  I updated my version of R and then it worked.

Comment: Nice. I recommend updating your question to mention the version of R and platform (e.g. 64-bit Windows 7, or whatever it is) that you were using. Also, please add some sample data, so that anyone using that version could try running your code. Then add the answer below that updating to version (fill in the blank) was all that was needed for it to work.