# Use for loop to plot multiple figures and output them to pdf file, But just get the last figure

Tags: r, plot

```
pdf("test.pdf")
for (i in length(dis_pos)){
    fic <- chr1[ chr1$pos < dis_pos[i]+500 & chr1$pos >=dis_pos[i], ]
    plot(fic$pos,fic$count,type='h')
}
dev.off()
```

I wanted to plot many figures according to the `length` of variable `dis_pos`. And I just got the last figure in `pdf` file. 
I mean, If the variable `dis_pos` equals `12`, how can I get all the `12` picture in `test.pdf` file, not the **12**th figure?

Comment: What "did not work" in the first loop? Was there an error message?

Comment: @Tw UxTLi51Nus Thanks. That's exactly the same question I face.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395410/how-to-print-r-graphics-to-multiple-pages-of-a-pdf-and-multiple-pdfs The link have the same question I encounter, but I cannot find a way to fix it.

Comment: How many plots did your for-loop create (without printing to pdf)? Hard to troubleshoot your code when no [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) is provided.

Comment: `i in 1:length(dis_pos)` not `i in length(dis_pos)`.

Comment: @Axeman you got it.