# How to export R plots to multipage PDF with renderPlot() in Shiny?

Tags: r, pdf, plot, shiny, multipage

I am forced to output multiple plots not in the static device. But I dynamically create variable number of plots in Shiny with renderPlot. I can successfully create separate pdf files for each device using the function pdf() within the renderPlot.

I have tried to make multipage pdf file as it is specified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395410/how-to-print-r-graphics-to-multiple-pages-of-a-pdf-and-multiple-pdfs) and in other similar posts. However in my case the created pdf file has the damaged contents (size of 7 kb) and can't be open. My code after simplification looks as follows.

```
for (PlotI in 1:PlotN)
{
  poObject <- plotOutput(outputId = PlotI)
  insertUI(selector = '#AnyPlaceHolder', where = "beforeBegin", 
           ui = poObject, multiple = FALSE, immediate = FALSE)
} # for PlotI
fnPDF <- paste0(tempdir(), '\\', 'plot.pdf')
pdf(file = fnPDF, width = 7, height = 4, onefile = TRUE, title = 'R output',
    paper = 'a4', pointsize = 1/PlotResolution, compress = TRUE)
for (PlotI in 1:PlotN)
{
  local(
    {
      PlotJ <- PlotI
      output[[PlotJ]] <- renderPlot(
        {
          opar <- par(no.readonly = TRUE)
          par(mar = c(2,4,2,0.5))
          plot(AnyTimeSeries[[PlotJ]])
          par(opar)                
        } 
      ) # renderPlot
    }
  ) # local
} # for PlotI
dev.off()
```

What is wrong?